# How I can load an image in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I'm new at this.

I'm trying to create a landing page, when I add the image it just won't show up.

Is it because I'm not locating it correctly? If so, how should I do it correctly?

Or what could the problem be?

Thanks in advance

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0):

**Procedure**

1. Using Windows Explorer, place the custom image file in the Images directory of the Visual Studio project.
2. In Visual Studio, open the project's Solution Explorer browser.
3. Right-click the images folder and select Add > Add Existing Item.

Comment: I'm a Mac user. How do I do that in Mac?